# Publishing Power Bi report with a Dynamic Excel Source

Tags: powerbi

How can I publish a report on Power Bi that uses a dynamic excel file to import data.
I want to keep the excel file at some place other than sharepoint from where I can update the excel file whenever I want.
What is a possible way for this?

I tried importing excel through Sharepoint, but the problem is I dont want a limitation where we have to go through a credentials system to import the excel file.

I want to place an excel file at a place from where the data can be updated regularly and will be reflected in the published report.

Comment: You don't want credentials to be required for users to edit the excel sheet, or you don't want the dataset to require credentials to access it?